# Parsing an Email Attachment w Paperclip - Possible w/o a tempfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, actionmailer

My rails 3 app on heroku receives incoming emails. I want to be able to accept attachments but can't get rails to process the attachments without erroring.

The ideal would be to pass the attachment provided by ActionMailer.

```
message_all = Mail.new(params[:message])
 message_all.attachments.each do |a|
 attachments.each do |a|
 .attachments.build(
   :attachment => a
  )
 end
end
```

It errors with: `NoMethodError (undefined method`rewind' for #)` 
Where attachments is a model, with attachment is paperclip

Ideas y? Is there a different way to pass the attachment = a , to paperclip?

I tried another approach, creating a tempfile:

```
tempfile = File.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.filename}", "w+")
tempfile << a.body
tempfile.puts
attachments.build(
:attachment => File.open(tempfile.path) )
```

The problem with the tempfile is files without extentions "blah" instead of "blah.png" are breaking paperclip which is why I want to avoid the tempfile. and creating Identity errors, imagemagick doesn't know what they are w/o the ext.

hugely appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the methods that you are using is that they don't contain all of the necessary information for paperclip like the content type and the original filename. I wrote a [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/12/09/receiving-and-saving-incoming-email-images-and-attachments-with-paperclip-and-rails-3/) about this a while back and how you could fake the format and use an email attachment as a paperclip attachment.

The bottom line was to do this:

```
file = StringIO.new(attachment)
file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
file.original_filename = attachment.filename
file.content_type = attachment.mime_type
```

Comment: That first line should probably read file = StringIO.new(attachment.decoded)

Comment: @Steve Your blog is down.

Comment: @Smooth thanks for the heads up. It seems to be working ok for me now. Hopefully just a temporary glitch.